# Delete Trigger After Sending Embed | Discord.js

Tags: javascript, triggers, command, discord.js, embed

I tried make the bot delete the trigger command after sending an embed but when i run the command it deletes both trigger and embed

My code:

```
bot.on('message', message=>{
    
    let args = message.content.substring(prefix.length).split(" ");
    switch(args[0]){
        case 'bronze':
            if (message.content.toLowerCase().includes("!bronze")) {
                message.delete();
                }
            
            const embed = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
                .setColor('#cc6633')
                .setTitle('title')
                .setDescription('text')
                .setThumbnail('my thumbnail')
                .addFields(
                    { name: '\u200B', value: '\u200B' },
                    { name: 'text', value: 'text' },
                    { name: 'text', value: 'text', inline: true },
                    { name: 'text', value: 'text', inline: true },
                )
                .addField('text', '<@&720343920873046105>')
                .addField('\u200B', '\u200B')
                .setTimestamp()
                .setFooter(`footer`, 'my photo');
            



    }
})
```

Comment: are you sure the embed actually gets sent? Because I can't see that in your code.

Comment: yes it gets send

Answer (score 0):

This has a very easy fix:

```
message.delete();
message.channel.send(embed):
```

You can also add a delay (in milliseconds) as a parameter for the `message.delete()` method.

Comment: you can just define another embed and then send that with another `message.channel.send(embed2);`.